# Void method in label

Tags: java, methods, void

Class n.1:

```
     void visualizza(){
            System.out.println("Testing")
.....
        }
```

Class n2 (JFrame):

```
label1.setText(obj1.visualizza());
```

Netbeans tell me error: "void type not allowed here"

Comment: you need to return a String...

Comment: i know. but I need to use void visualizza() on the label

Comment: no you don't. you need to have `visualizza` to return string.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why do you believe you *need to use void ... on the label*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `void visualizza()` method doesn't return any `String`.

`System.out.println("Testing")` just prints the String `Testing` on console.

But for `setText()` method you need to pass a `String` as parameter.

Most probably this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
String visualizza() {
    return "Testing";
}
```

Then-

```
label1.setText(obj1.visualizza());
```

***PS:*** Please do your own research at least on the basics before referring to stackoverflow. Good luck!